# Copy images back to camera and make the camera recognize them

Tags: windows-vista, camera

Is there a way to get jpeg images taken with a digital camera and downloaded to the computer back to the memory card and make the camera recognize them, so that you can view it in the camera display (e.g. to show others)?

What doesn't seem work

- Copy the images directly to the memory card root
- Copy the images directly to the DCIM folder on the memory card
- Copy the images directly to the DCIM/99CANON folder (or similar) on the memory card
- Attach the camera to the computer via USB, find it in the explorer any try to move the images back to the folder where the camera put the recently taken pictures. Explorer doesn't allow me to copy anything to that place.

Canon IXUS 870IS on Vista, with Vista drivers installed.

Comment: My Canon never recognized the pictures if I tried putting them back on the camera. It would be nice if there was actually a way.

Comment: Don't you have a Manager that comes with the digital camera? They usually have a option to upload pictures on the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nicu Zecheru (comments on the question) for hint.

What worked:

Cannon ZoomBrowser EX does indeed have a command to copy the selected images to a memory card. So you have to mount the memory card directly in the pc, select the images in ZoomBrowser and make it copy them to the card. The camera did indeed recognize them afterwards.

Comment: Glad you could solve your problem!

Comment: Note that ZoomBrowser can only copy images back that have exactly a resolution supported by the camera (i.e. no crops or non-metadata rotations)